How to post bill to GL using workflow in netsuite?
I have a workflow approval requirement.
a)Vendor Bill is Created with Amount <= $10,000.
VB is routed to Controller for Approval.
Controller Approves VB and it gets posted to the GL.
b)If VB Amount >=$10,000.
VB is first routed to Controller for first Approval.
Its then routed to VP of Finance as a second Approver.
VP of Finance Approvers the Bill and it gets posted.
**If Controller is out, Olga can log in as Controller and approve it, but she will not be able to do level 2 approval on the same VB under any role. In this case, the VB will be outed to CEO for second approval.
What I did,
I have created 2 level approval workflow that is, for controller and VP. But how to post bill only after its approved by both approvers?
